# Problems with Play's routing file after migrating to 2.4

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I migrated my java play framework app to play 2.4 and am running into problems with the changed router. I am getting this error message:

```
[NullPointerException: null]
In /home/apps/kikstar/target/scala-2.11/routes/main/router/Routes.scala:957

954    // @LINE:77
955    case controllers_Application_login35_route(params) =>
956      call { 
957        controllers_Application_login35_invoker.call(Application_1.login())
958      }
959  
960    // @LINE:80
961    case controllers_Application_javascriptRoutes36_route(params) =>
962      call {
```

The line in the router looks like this:

```
POST        /login                            controllers.Application.login()
```

and the call in the frontend

```
@(rootForm: Form[Root])

  @helper.form(action = routes.Application.login(), 'id -> "userform") {
    @helper.inputText(rootForm("username"))
    @helper.inputPassword(rootForm("pass"))
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  }
```

and the method in Application

```
public Result login() {
    Form<Root> filledForm = rootForm.bindFromRequest();
    Root created = filledForm.get();
    Logger.info(created.username + " " + created.pass);
    ...
}
```

Every other Route is working. This is the only route beeing called through a Form helper though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, as much as I like Play, I don't like things like this, and they usually appear after migrations and so on. I'm not sure about the reason, is it the IDE or SBT. I believe calling `sbt clean compile` should do the trick or clearing the IDE cache if there is any. I'm assuming you went through the [Migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24#Routing) .

Comment: Shouldn't this be done automatically using the `activator run` command?

Comment: I don't think it calls `clean` as a full compilation after it is usually expensive, but I rarely use the Activator directly. I believe it tends to use incremental compilation as much as possible, which may be an sbt thing, since it is underlying the Activator. It wouldn't be unheard of that cleaning and recompiling the whole thing fixes the application.